# Using example code to demonstrate the use case

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, example-code

Take a look at the code in [this recently closed question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101518/a-possibly-terrible-alternative-to-conditionals-full-of-null-checks). It clearly consists of two parts.

1. The method, which OP wants us to review.
2. An example (hypothetical?) code, which demonstrates the use case of above method.

Now, to make this question on-topic, OP can either remove part 2 completely or replace it with actual code, which is most likely a lot larger and a lot more complex, than three stub classes. I wonder though if the question will improve as a result of either of those actions. I personally as reviewer would much prefer the original version of this question, as it both (a) shows just enough context to understand what the person is asking and (b) doesn't force me to dive into the semantics of classes which are irrelevant to the question asked.

Opinions? Should hypothetical code be allowed in general if it is used to provide context to actual code?

Comment: For this question I agree with you. Nevertheless it would be better if the code in question is broken in two pieces, the first targeting the method and the second targeting the usage.

Comment: I've actually just voted to reopen this question. There's very real code to be reviewed in the middle. It'd be nice to see the more hypothetical code separated in a quote block or something though.

Comment: Good edit @RubberDuck. Voted to reopen too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I went edited the question and voted to reopen. I split the real, reviewable code away from the example call, which is now in a quote block. The edit bumps in into the review queue for the community to decide if it should be reopened. I expect that it will be. Thank you for bringing this to meta.

---

The community has voted to reopen this question. Thank you again for bringing it to our attention.